# jQuery .html() argument

Tags: javascript, jquery

How does this work in regard to arguments (I'm using this in sorting a select box):

```
$(this).html( $("option", $(this)).sort( function(a, b) {return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1}));
```

If `$(this)` represents a "select" menu, argument is a collection of sorted "option" values. Or is there a better/cleaner way to explain what's happening?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked for an explanation, here's a plain English explanation:

> For this `<select>` element, take the existing `<option>`, put them
>   into an array, and sort them by their text value, then replace the
>   existing html with the new sorted options.

Equivalent jQuery for your code, with variable names to help you see what's happening:

```
    var currentOptions = $("option", $(this));
    var sortedOptions = currentOptions.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
    });
    $(this).html(sortedOptions);
```

The sorting that occurs is a JavaScript method, read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Answer (score 1):

When passing an element to the `html()` method, the element is removed from its previous location, and added to the selector, `$(this)` in this case.

So,

```
$(this).html( $("option", $(this) )     //is equal to:
$(this).html( $(this).find("option") ); //is similar to (in terms of elements):
$(this).find(":not(option)").remove();  // or

var temp = $("div").append($("option", this)); //Create temp container
$(this).html("");                              //Remove contents
$(this).append(temp.children());               //Append <option>
```

means: "Overwrite the current element with `<option>` elements at the current node."

Answer (score 0):

This is just a note to help you with your debugging, The previous answers to this question explain the exact answer for what you are asking but I just thought it might be helpful to let you know about this problem I came across last week. I wish I could remember the blog post where there were other people that had also found this problem.

There is a problem in jquery when you try to chain conditional statements the way you are putting them together. So:

```
return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1
```

will probably not give you the results you are expecting. Try this:

```
var isLessThan =  a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1;
return a.text == b.text ? 0 : isLessThan;
```

I know it is a bit of a pain but it will at least give you the answer you are expecting from that line of code.

Comment: How could that be a jquery issue?  That would be a javascript issue, no?  If so, why would a ternary not behave according to spec?